# linux find command output traversing

Tags: linux, command, find, traversal, output

I need to create a shell script that will simply find files (e.g. *.jpg) under particular source (e.g. /var/www/html/folder1/source/) and have to make some operations with the output returned by the Find command. Below is the command i have written in my script

```
outputvar = find /var/www/html/folder1/source/ -name \*.jpg
```

How can i make a traverse operation on a variable that store the output of the find command?

Comment: What operations do you want to do on each such file?

Comment: i need to zip all files of a each folder and after that will have to remove those files

Comment: Could you have file names which contain a space like character? Or are you sure that none of the `*.jpg` file names have spaces, e.g. no `photo\ of\ flower.jpg` ??

Comment: Yes there may be space or any special character... In this case i don't know how to handle such files while zipping.

Comment: I slightly improved my answer (about spaces in filenames), but you really should read more material about Unix scripting.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to put the output of your `find` command in a file, e.g.

```
find /var/www/html/folder1/source/ -name \*.jpg > /tmp/find.out
```

You could also put that output in a shell variable, e.g.

```
outfindvar=$(find /var/www/html/folder1/source/ -name \*.jpg)
```

and then you could iterate on them

```
for jpgfile in $outfindvar; do 
   ## do something with $jpgfile
done
```

If you could have files with spaces in their name, be careful. In that case, consider using the `-print0` action of `find`; or perhaps use an auxiliary script for the `-exec` action.

You really should read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

You may want to start your script with

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
```

while debugging it, and remove the `-vx` once your script is working well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question is How can i traverse "outfindvar" used in you example above?

Comment: I ran above code but got error "/var/www/html/folder1/source: is a directory". Please suggest

Comment: Did you start reading the *Advanced Bash Scripting Guide* or some other good material? It explains things much better than we can. I have the feeling you don't understand some basics about shells and Linux commands. Read also the documentation of `find(1)`, e.g. with `man find`

Comment: Okay i will first reading that article and see if could get solution.... thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

How about [piping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) the output to whatever else it is you want to do with it?

```
find /var/www/html/folder1/source/ -name \*.jpg | other_command
```

Comment: Piping seems something useful but i could not understand that in my case how would i traverse with "outputvar" of my example. Can you please provide few more details

Comment: The output is a series of strings (file paths), if `other_command` (which can be an arbitrarily complex chain) can read `stdin`, it will operate on each string, which I assume is what you mean by "traverse".